# Get the current page title and show the title in wordpress text sidebar widget

Tags: wordpress, widget

How to get the current page title and show on text widget sidebar in wordpress?

can anyone help would be appreciated?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could for example use the "PHP Code widget": http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/

And then paste something like the following in the configuration section of the widget:

`<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Using a text / code widget (that allows you to enter code, not a standard text box)

```
<?php  
    $here = wp_title();
       echo $here ; ?>
```